# lubridate yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX conversion unexpected. Bug?

Tags: r, lubridate

Very unexpected behaviour when parsing "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"-string (ISO 8601)

```
> as_datetime("2017-03-22T15:48:00.000Z")
[1] "2017-03-21 23:00:00 UTC"

> packageDescription("lubridate")$Version 
[1] "1.6.0"
```

Could someone explain the rationale for this?

edit: Seems like a bug, see [issue #536](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/536)

Comment: can you explain a little bit more/give a little bit more context? `strptime("2017-03-22T15:48:00.000Z",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` does work for me: `[1] "2017-03-22 15:48:00 EDT"` (because `strptime` discards trailing characters ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**: resolved in `lubridate` commit [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/cf7822ad69000f6bf69eacd92b4f6f2fff938091) (May 2017). Works with `lubridate` 1.7.4, probably some earlier versions as well.

Without digging into the guts of `as_datetime`,
I think this may be a combination of (1) `as_datetime` 
not being able to handle (i.e., ignore) the `T` in your format;
(2) conversion from local to UTC time zone.

```
dstr <- "2017-03-22T15:48:00.000Z"
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(dstr)
## [1] "2017-03-22 04:00:00 UTC"
```

If `as_datetime()` ignores everything after the `T`
that gets us to midnight on 2017-03-22. However, this is
taken as midnight *in my local time zone* which is GMT+04,
so the resulting time is 04:00:00. Presumably your local time
is GMT-01.

If you manually substitute a space for the `T` things work better (you can use
`stringr::str_replace` if you prefer)

```
as_datetime(sub("T"," ",dstr))
## [1] "2017-03-22 19:48:00 UTC"
```

Or use `strptime`:

```
strptime(dstr,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "2017-03-22 15:48:00 EDT"
```

(note that `strptime` automatically discards *trailing* characters)

For what it's worth Dirk Eddelbuettel's `anytime` package handles this case:

```
 anytime(dstr)
 ## [1] "2017-03-22 15:48:00 EDT"
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains the issue. I'm filing a bug report. 
As the date-format is ISO 8601 (i.e _very_ standard) I assume this will wreck someones day. Fortunately I've been parsing csv with `readr` which automagically infers `readr::col_datetime` as columnspec which is compliant except parsing the `T`

Answer (score 5):

If you have imported your data in the format presented here and you want to use lubridate to convert it into a date-time object I would recommend using the `ymd_hms` function of lubridate.

In your case it would look like this:

```
ymd_hms("2017-03-22T15:48:00.000Z")
[1] "2017-03-22 15:48:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I use `as_datetime`? I assume to parse a ISO 8601 `datetime` string and (lazily) get _date_ and _time_